# C++ Не добавляются элементы в односвязный список (STL list)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, функции, list, передача-параметров

Нужна простая программа для демонстрации работы библиотеки **< list >**. Реализованы все функции, но проблему достаточно рассмотреть на одной из них, остальное я сделаю по аналогии.

Код программы:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
list <int> intList;

/* Добавление в конец списка*/
void addEnd(list <int> &l) {
    int num;
    cout << "Введите число, которое нужно добавить:\n";
    cin >> num;
    l.push_back(num);
}

/* Добавление в начало списка */
void addBegin(list <int> &l) {
    int num;
    cout << "Введите число, которое нужно добавить:\n";
    cin >> num;
    l.push_front(num);
}

/* Вставить число после указанного значения */
void insertAfter(list <int>& l) {
    if (!l.empty()) {
        int after, num;
        cout << "Введите значение, после которого нужно вставить число:\n";
        cin >> after;
        cout << "Введите число, которое нужно вставить:\n";
        cin >> num;
        list <int> ::iterator it;
        for (it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++)
            if (*it == after) break;
        l.insert(it, num);
    }
}

/* Вывод всего списка в консоль */
void printList(list <int> l) {
    if (!l.empty()) {
        list <int> ::iterator it;
        for (it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++)
            cout << *it << '\t';
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

/* Поиск в списке */
void searchInList(list <int> l) {
    if (!l.empty()) {
        int num;
        bool b = false;
        cout << "Введите число, которое нужно найти:\n";
        cin >> num;
        list <int> ::iterator it;
        for (it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) {
            if (*it == num) b = true;
        }
        if (b) cout << "Такое число есть в списке!";
        else cout << "Такого числа нету в списке!";
    }
}

void deleteInList(list <int> &l) {
    if (!l.empty()) {
        int num;
        bool b = false;
        cout << "Введите число, которое нужно удалить:\n";
        cin >> num;
        list <int> ::iterator it;
        for (it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++)
            if (*it == num) {
                b = true;
                l.erase(it);
            }
        if (b) cout << "Элемент успешно удалён!";
        else cout << "Такого числа нету в списке!";
    }
}

/* Блок вызова меню */
void printMenu() {
    cout << "1. Добавить число в начало списка";
    cout << "\n2. Добавить число в конец списка";
    cout << "\n3. Добавить число после указаного значения";
    cout << "\n4. Вывести весь список";
    cout << "\n5. Поиск значения в списке";
    cout << "\n6. Удаление узла";
    cout << "\n0. Выход\n";
}
void getChoise(list <int> l) {
    int choise;
    cin >> choise;
    switch (choise) {
    case 1: system("cls"); addEnd(l); break;
    case 2: system("cls"); addBegin(l); break;
    case 3: system("cls"); insertAfter(l); break;
    case 4: system("cls"); printList(l); break;
    case 5: system("cls"); searchInList(l); break;
    case 6: system("cls"); deleteInList(l); break;
    case 0: exit(0);
    default: cout << "Введите значение из списка!\n"; getChoise(l);
    }
}
void callMenu(list <int> l) {
    printMenu();
    getChoise(l);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int a = 30;
    intList.push_back(10);
    intList.push_back(20);
    intList.push_back(a);

    cout << "Razmer = " << intList.size() << endl;

    while(true) callMenu(intList);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если смотреть через отладчик, то пока программа внутри функции, список увеличивается, и этот элемент стает на свое законное место. Но как только управление переходит обратно в main, состояние списка сбрасывается до начального и элемент пропадает.

P.s. я на 1м курсе и только учу с++, так что не кидайте минусы в репутацию если вопрос слишком тривиальный :)

Comment: Ваш код вообще не компилируется - не указано, что такое `l`, которое вы передаете в вызове `addEnd(l)`.

Comment: пожалуй, кину полный код

Answer (score 3):

Все ваши проблемы от того, что вы передаете список то по ссылке, то по значению.

И там, где вы передаете его по значению, создается *копия*, которая по выходе из функции уничтожается. Например, вы передаете в `callMenu` ваш `intList` по значению - но при очередном вызове он будет так же пуст, как и при первом. Потому что все, что вы с ним делаете - вы делаете с копией, а `intList` как был пуст, так таким и остается...

Какой вообще смысл, кстати, передавать контейнер по значению? Если он не изменяется функцией - передавайте его как константную ссылку, если изменяется - как неконстантную...